# Make play button display on hover 1 image at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i'm trying to make it so when someone hovers on an image it makes the play button turn up only on that image, I have a few different effects on the image so I've had to make it so that when i hover one class it shows another one with it too using java, only problem is I have 9 images that need to show the play button on hover indivudally but when I hover over 1 image it shows the play icon on all of the images at once,

Is there an easier way to do this so that the play icon only shows when I'm hovering the one specific image?

Javascript:

```
$(".portbg1").hover( function () {
$(this).addClass("active");
$(".playbutton").addClass("active");
}, function (){
$(this).removeClass("active");
$(".playbutton").removeClass("active");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="port_item"><div class="playbutton"></div><div 
class="portbg1"><div class="port_item_title" data-modal="#modalOne"> . 
<h4>Showreel</h4></div></div></div>
```

There's also portbg2, portbg3, portbg4 etc... portbg9

CSS:

```
.playbutton {
   position: absolute;
   background-image: url(IMAGES/openicon.png);
   background-size: 80px 80px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   z-index: 1;
   opacity: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: all 0.2s;
}

.playbutton:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}

.active {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't even need to use JS for that. Just use the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class: that should achieve what you need. If you really need to use JS: the reason why your code does not work as intended is because you're selecting *all* the play buttons on hovering any individual item. Use `$(this).find(.playbutton)` to scope the selection to the nested play button of a specific item instead.

Comment: Please go to jsfiddle and make a simple demo of your issue there. It make us easier to solve the problem.

Comment: `$(".playbutton")` is a global selector.  You have to use a contextual lookup to find the playbutton relative to the image hovered.

Comment: Yea I need it to find and enable the locally nested playbutton to the port_item i'm hovering i'm just not sure how to put the find the nested play button part into my java code

Comment: `$(this).closest('.port_item').find('.playbutton')`

Comment: Cheers Taplar! works good

Answer (score 2):

Just doing :

```
$(this).siblings('.playbutton').addClass("active");
```

doing the same on remove class.

So finally would be:

```
$(this).addClass("active").siblings('.playbutton').addClass("active");
```

Comment: perfect thanks man, combined with Taplars so I can use code globally for all the port_items, $(".port_item").hover( function () {
  $(this).closest('.port_item').find('.playbutton').addClass("active");
}, function (){
  $(this).closest('.port_item').find('.playbutton').removeClass("active");
});